# How to switch between different calendars?

Tags: events, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I have a bunch of calendars in my google calendar account. I figured out how to add an event under one of the calendars, but is there a way to switch to a different calendar through update() when you already have the events created?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

> [**Events: move**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/move#request)
>
> Moves an event to another calendar, i.e. changes an event's organizer.

Here is a sample code for `move()`:

```
$result = $service->events->move('primary', 'eventId', 'destinationCalendarId');

// Print the updated date.
echo $result->getUpdated();
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I need! Thank you!